# Xamarin Forms: Is it possible to add disclosure indicator in Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

[image]

I have a `TextCell` which adds a disclosure indicator in the iOS side of my `Xamarin Forms` app:

```
<TextCell Text="Japanese" StyleId="disclosure"/>
```

I would also like to do the same thing for the android side but I can't seem to find any custom renderers to do such thing.

Has anyone been able to do this? I would really appreciate if someone could point me to that direction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [design guidelines](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html), it is recommended to not use right-pointing carets (disclosure indicators) on line items in Android.

> **Don't use right-pointing carets on line items**
>
> A common pattern on other platforms is the display of right-pointing carets on line items that allow the user to drill deeper into additional content.
>
> Android does not use such indicators on drill-down line items. Avoid them to stay consistent with the platform and in order to not have the user guess as to what the meaning of those carets may be.

[image]

**EDIT 1:**

But if you still want to add the indicator, you can use an image for that.

[Download the icon](https://material.io/icons/#ic_chevron_right) and add as drawable to android project. And register the renderer as following:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TextCell), typeof(StandardTextCellRenderer))]
namespace AppNamespace.Droid
{
    public class StandardTextCellRenderer : TextCellRenderer
    {

        protected override Android.Views.View GetCellCore(Cell item, Android.Views.View convertView, Android.Views.ViewGroup parent, Android.Content.Context context)
        {
            var cell = base.GetCellCore(item, convertView, parent, context);

            switch (item.StyleId)
            {
                case "disclosure":
                    var bmp = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(cell.Resources, Resource.Drawable.ic_chevron_right);
                    var bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(cell.Resources, Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(bmp, 50, 50, true));
                    bitmapDrawable.Gravity = GravityFlags.Right | GravityFlags.CenterVertical;
                    cell.SetBackground(bitmapDrawable);
                    break;
            }
            return cell;
        }
    }
}
```